# Android.widget.framelayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

My app keeps crashing. I'm trying to create a tab swype navigation setup. here is my code.

adapter class

```
package tabsswipe.adapter;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
//import fragments

import edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainFragment;
//import edu.wmich.tabswithswipe.PostFragment;
//import edu.wmich.tabswithswipe.SuggestFragment;

 public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Main fragment activity
       return new MainFragment();
    case 1:
        // Suggest fragment activity
        //return new SuggestFragment();
    case 2:
        // Post fragment activity
        //return new PostFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

Main activity

```
package edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119;

import tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

//tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Main", "Photo", "Share"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //adding the tabs to the action bar
    for(String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    //on viewpager swiping, make the respective tab selected
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //on changing the page, make tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Main fragment

```
package edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name = "edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainFragment"
        android:label = "@string/main_fragment_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

the goal is to add more tabs so i can swype to navigate between fragments. it looks like i just have a casting error but nothing looks wrong to me. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Here is my main XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Fragment XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: instead of showing your manifest which is of no help to the problem why not show the xml layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post your xml layout file? And also the stacktrace?

If I had to guess I would say double check that your container `R.id.container` is declared as a `ViewPager` in your layout file.

EDIT: after your comment

In your java code you use ' viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);'
Which means you try to cast the element called 'container' as a viewPager.

But in your xml file, the element named container is a 'FrameLayout'.

If you want to use a ViewPage, you need to change your layout, instead of:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

you need:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainActivity" 
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" > 
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  
        android:id="@+id/container" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        /> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Or if you do want to use a FrameLayout, you need to change your cast. Instead of:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
```

use

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
```

Comment: Activity_main XML:
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Comment: Edited my response. You need to decide if you want to use a framelayout or a viewpager

Comment: UPDATE: Just launched and i can see my tabs now. but it crashed again. this time the error is a nullpointerException

Comment: Look in the logcat where the nullpointerexception occured. It should give you a line number.

Answer (score 1):

As you have been told it's probable that you made a mistake not declaring `R.id.container` as a ViewPager, but if everything is correct try doing `Project->clean` sometimes the IDE just gets confused and messes up some ids, specially if you have been copy pasting xml code

Comment: Now it says "Didn't find class android.view.viewPager on path /data/app/edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119-1.apk

Comment: I want to use a ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem for your null pointer is in you switch. Make sure you have a fragment called 'MainFragment', add `break` and add a `default:` otherwise your switch will return null.

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Main fragment activity
       return new MainFragment();
       break;
    case 1:
        return new MainFragment();
       break;
    case 2:
        return new MainFragment();
       break;
    default:
        return new MainFragment();
        break; 
    }
return null;
```

Comment: i have two more fragments too add...look at my main activity. ill build them and set them up here and see what happens. Thanks!! you guys are life savers

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that solved the question you asked.

Comment: Changing the frameLayout and getting the rest of my fragments in there fixed my problem. Thanks!!